# Unable to connect WebSocket API hosted on Socket.IO

Tags: ios, iphone, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to connect to WebSocket API : http://kaboom.rksv.net/ using Socket.IO framework for iOS, i am banging my head to understand how to open the connection with this.

I have tried many possibilities and it did not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If the server talks the WebSocket protocol, you have to use a WebSocket client library. On the other hand, if the server talks the Socket.IO protocol, you have to use a Socket.IO client library. Below is an excerpt from [Socket.IO page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket.IO) in Wikipedia.

> *Socket.IO is not a WebSocket library with fallback options to other realtime protocols. It is a custom realtime transport protocol implementation on top of other realtime protocols. Its protocol negotiation parts cause a client supporting standard WebSocket to not being able to contact a Socket.IO server. And **a Socket.IO implementing client cannot talk to a non-Socket.IO based WebSocket** or Long Polling Comet server. Therefore Socket.IO requires using the Socket.IO libraries on both client and server side.*

Comment: Yes i am the Socket.IO client library which is provided by Socket.IO but still i'm stuck. I am not able to establish a connection